# $f \in L^1(\lambda) $ and $ \mu \ll \lambda \implies f \in L^1(\mu)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

The question is the one in the title. In essence, if a function $f$ is in $L^1$ with respect to a measure $\mu$, and $\mu$ is dominated by $\lambda$ then is that true that $f \in L^1$ with respect to $\mu$?

Comment: I noticed that I swapped the role of $\mu$ and $\lambda$. Now I corrected the question.

Comment: what means that $\mu$ is "dominated" by $\lambda $? The title says that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous respect to $\lambda $

Comment: It means absolutely continuous. Read in Generalizations subsection (under the Absolute continuity of measures section) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false: took a function $g>0$ and set $\mu:=g\cdot \lambda$ for $g\in L_1(\lambda )$ such that $g\notin L_2(\lambda )$, then $\mu\ll\lambda $ but $g\notin L_1(\mu)$.

Comment: Clever! Thank you @Masacroso!